# How to execute requests postrequest in scrapy

Tags: python, post, scrapy

I want to start my scrapy spider with a post request

```
import requests
data = {
        'lang': 'en',
        'limit': '10',
        'offset': '0',
        'path': '/content/swisscom/en/about/news',
        'query': '' 
    }
    s_url = 'https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search'
    r = requests.post(url=s_url, data=data)
```

As long I execute the request directly from python using the requests package like above everything works fine. However as soon as I incorporate it in my spider using the scrapy's 'Formrequest'

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class example(scrapy.Spider):
name = "example"

def start_requests(self):
    data = {
        'lang':    'en',
        'limit': '10',
        'offset': '0',
        'path':    '/content/swisscom/en/about/news',
        'query': ''    
    }
    s_url = 'https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search'
    return[FormRequest(url=s_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse )]

def parse(self, response):
    test = json.loads(response.text)
    for quote in test['results']:
        yield {
            'url': quote['url']
            }
```

I get the following error

```
2018-10-11 11:45:35 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:[]
2018-10-11 11:45:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-10-11 11:45:35 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-10-11 11:45:35 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-10-11 11:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2018-10-11 11:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2018-10-11 11:45:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2018-10-11 11:45:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <POST https://www.swisscom.ch/etc/swisscom/servlets/public/gcr/news/search>
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2018-10-11 11:45:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Could anyone please tell me what the error message means and why my request is not working in scrapy while everything is totally fine using 'requests.post'?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Meanwhile I figured out the answer. Had to send some special headers with the request using FormRequest in Scrapy, while it seems requests.post sends the right headers by default.

Comment: Yes, usually you have to change the request header's `content-type` to `application/json`. And I don't  think `FormRequest` is necessary, you can try `yield scrapy.Request(url=s_url, callback=self.parse, method='POST', body=json.dumps(data))`